# Regexp that contains exactly one repetition of 011

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression that defines a language consisting of all strings of 0s and 1s that contains **exactly one** substring 011.

This is my approach:  1* 0* (10*)* 011(1)* (0+10)*. I do not know how to fix this, also there is probably more efficient way to solve this..

011 Accept

111000101001011 Accept

110011  Accept

1101011 Accept

110011010   Accept

011011  Accept //it is accepting this one, which is wrong

111111  Reject

101011  Accept

0001011 Accept

Comment: [cs.se] is a better place to ask questions about regular expressions that define languages. [so] is for programming questions, and programming regular expressions are different from CS regular expressions.

Comment: If a lookahead is supported `^(?![01]*011[01]*011)[01]*011[01]*$` https://regex101.com/r/3kwbiz/1

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression to solve this problem?

Comment: @Barmar will do that in future! I have managed to fix my mistake

Comment: @Karl, I'd ask the opposite question: why would one not use a regular expression to solve this problem? Can you suggest a non-regex solution that you prefer to Bird #4's solution?

Comment: As to what the OP means by "regular expression" let's not forget there is a "regex" tag.

Answer (score 2):

If supported, you can use a negative lookahead asserting not 2 repetitions of 001.

If that is the case, match `011` between optional repetitions of either 0 or 1 using a character class `[01]*`

```
^(?![01]*?011[01]*?011)[01]*011[01]*$
```

See a demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6sNjaW/1) for the matches.

Comment: Lookarounds aren't in mathematical regular expressions, only in programming.

Comment: @CarySwoveland In this case yes, but is all depends on the location of the strings.

Comment: @Barmar I did not know that, thanks. I could not tell if this is about mathematical regular expressions.

Comment: Do you need `[01]*$` or the `?`'s, or are they just for efficiency?

Comment: I see 248 steps are required at your regex101.com link. Removing `[01]*$` reduces that to 234. Then removing the two question marks increases 234 to 247. That is of course not definitive.

Comment: You seem to have anticipated my question, but I don't understand what you mean about the "location of the strings".

Comment: The key is "defines a language" in the question. That's an abstract computer science concept, not something working programmers do (although programming language designers do something like this).

Comment: @Barmar, I don't think the question is sufficiently clear for us to know what the OP wants to do, and he/she seems disinclined to clarify it. I assumed it was the type of regular expression that one finds at regex101.com, in part because of the "regex" tag, so my comments, and I assume the two answers given to date, are based on that assumption.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry for the late response, I read it but then forgot to reply. In my comment about the location of the strings I meant like for example the greedy https://regex101.com/r/09sJ8J/1 vs non greedy https://regex101.com/r/WkEjO0/1 if you know where the occurrences you want are positioned in the string. But I agree with you, that for this example it does not make a lot of difference using greedy or non greedy in the lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt without lookarounds:

`^(?>[01]*?011)([01]*?011)?+[01]*(?(1)(*FAIL)|)$`

[try here](https://regex101.com/r/xKraPX/1)

Explanation:

```
^               Match the start of the string
(?>[01]*?011)   Match everything up to and including the first 011, without allowing backtracking
([01]*?011)?+   Match everything up to and including the second 011, 
[01]*           Match remaining 1's and 0's
(?(1)(*FAIL)|)  If the second 011 was found, report a failure
$               Match the end of the string
```